# How to develop and Implement MDM server in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, mdm

I want to develop a MDM solution for iOS7 and want to implement

- App whitelist
- App blacklist

Features. Can any one please give me some starting point, from where I can start ?

Comment: Sure.  Just ask Google, Yahoo, Bing or whatever about "MDM server iOS."